# Angular, looping through nested components

Tags: angular, nested, angular6

I am using Angular 6, trying to write out hardcoded data using nested components and a ngloop, but it wont let me.

I have a component Post:

```
export class Post {
    title: string;
    constructor(title: string) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

I create a list of Posts(with dummy data) in my PostListComponent:

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

posts: Post[];

constructor() {
  this.posts = [
    new Post("title1"),
    new Post("title2"),
    new Post("title3"),
  ];
}
```

and the html for this:

```
<div class="card-container">
      <mat-card class="example-card" 
      *ngFor="let postToDisplay of posts">

        <display-post [post]="postToDisplay">
        </display-post>

      </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

now.. I want to deliver the postToDisplay variable from the loop to the display-post component where i try to write this out:

```
{{ post.title }}
```

and the typescript, very simple with just an input:

```
export class DisplayPostComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() post: Post;
}
```

I am receiving this error message in the developer console:

Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'post' since it isn't a known property of 'display-post'.
1. If 'display-post' is an Angular component and it has 'post' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: Most likely you forgot to add `DisplayPostComponent` to your module.

Comment: Share your module ts file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you're import the component or module correctly in your applicaction.

This kind of error is mainly by miss injection component or module in your workspace.